# Is it possible to pass a Socket.Handle from a C# Application to a ASP.NET Web Application running on the same server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

Is it possible to pass a Socket.Handle from a C# Application to a ASP.NET Web Application running on the same server?

I have looked around and found examples of passing C# socket to un-managed code, however this is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm very curious about why you'd want to do that.

As for the answer, no, I am 99% sure it is not possible, because unless I am very much mistaken socket handles are scoped to the process at the OS level.

EDIT:

Based on the comments, it sounds like you'd want to make the server process run a WCF service on IPC transport that the ASP.NET application can use to pass along commands to the hardware.

An added benefit is that if you use WCF and eventually need to move the ASP.NET site to another box, you can switch to TCP transport with relatively little fuss.

Comment: I have a C# server application that holds persistent socket connections from hardware(embedded C) in the field. This server currently updates a SQL database with packet information from the hardware in the field. I then have an ASP.NET web-UI which uses the same database to display information about the hardware. The web-ui allows interaction with the hardware. Currently the web-UI updates the database. The C# application has a timer that uses sql CDC to check for changed data and then sends back to the field hardware. If I could get the socket handle from the C# app in the web-ui, I could get

Comment: thanks for the info, I will have to look into WCF and IPC. I currently have a working prototype C# application which uses TCP.

Comment: I looked into WCF and have created a test WCF service. If I have my ASP.NET web application call a function from WCF I would then like WCF to call a function on my C# Application running on the server. Is this possible? The reason I need this is because my C# Application holds all the connected sockets and has all the socket handling code. I guess I could make the WCF Service have all the socket handling code? Though I would rather not... I am not sure what I do where now.

Comment: I am not sure I understand that last bit.  If actions in the ASP.NET invoke behavior in the hardware, you should host the WCF services in the same process as the existing service (that maintains TCP connections to the hardware).  If the hardware invokes behavior in the ASP.NET application, then you should host the WCF services in the ASP.NET application.

Comment: In my case - Actions in ASP.NET invoke behavior in the hardware. My windows Forms application currently handles all TCP connections and holds the sockets for each connected piece of hardware. From what I can tell, if I host the WCF service in my windows Forms application my asp.net and windows Forms applications can call functions within the WCF. However the WCF does not have access to the sockets/socket code in the windows Forms application. I am not sure how to make the ASP.NET call a WCF function which then in turn calls a windows forms function...

Comment: The appropriate venue is SO chat.  I'll convert this line of comments to a chat session shortly.  Presumably the Winforms application has a dictionary or collection of the TCP connections, right?  You need to be able to identify the device that you are communicating with on each connection, so there needs to be some identifier associated with that connection.  Assuming the collection of TCP connections is somehow globally accessible (through a singleton or static instance), you'd be able to find the connection that you need from within the WCF method and send whatever data was needed.

Comment: I have never used SO chat before. Do I have to do anything? Yes, the Winforms application has a dictionary with TCP connections. I use a unique serial number to address the specific device. The TCP connections at this point are not globally accessible. My WCF service is added to the winforms application with "Add Service Reference".. Do I need to add the WFC service to the same project as the winforms application, so that I can access global variables within the Winforms application?

Comment: Ahh, you see my original suggestion was to host the WCF methods *within* the application that manages the TCP connections (the Winforms app).  That will make it trivial to access the connections dictionary.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10893/discussion-between-chris-shain-and-mausimo)